# Router settings page: password accepted on mobile browser but not on desktop browser

Tags: windows-10, router

I recently reset my Huawei router to its factory defaults and found I could no longer log in to the router settings on my desktop - which is directly connected to the router with cat5. Having tried the same on my mobile I find that I can actually log in on the mobile browser with no problems.

I can log in and adjust settings with no problem using my mobile [the username and password are **valid**].

I can access the router settings page on my desktop but it won't accept the login credentials and keeps telling me the username or password is invalid.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on here? Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT (from comments):

Still using the same login ip - 192,168, etc etc and the internet connection is perfect. No problems connecting at all which is what makes this so weird. I can live with the issue, I just find it a pain to adjust settings on the mobile is all.

Comment: I recently reset my Huawei router to it's factory defaults  ..... Did you change the login IP address?   In your desktop NIC settings (system tray) is the desktop connected to the router with no errors showing?    Maybe dp a TCP/IP Reset on the desktop.

Comment: Still using the same login ip - 192,168, etc etc and the internet connection is perfect. No problems connecting at all which is what makes this so weird. I can live with the issue, I just find it a pain to adjust settings on the mobile is all.

Comment: TCP/IP Reset:   .....    Basic TCP/IP Reset
 
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: Have you tried to login in browser  private mode or using a browser that hasn't logged in before to see if it is some kind of caching issue?

Comment: If the internet is working on your desktop (and it has no wifi) then you must be typing in incorrect creds.  Possibly, the browser is auto-filling with your previous creds instead of the default ones.